# Can an A4-size PDF with 600dpi be printed as a poster?

Tags: posters

Suppose I have a PDF document of 600 dpi and A4 size.

Can it be printed as a 91.4cm x 121.9cm (36”x48”) poster without pixelation?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What resolution should a large format artwork for print be?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/487/what-resolution-should-a-large-format-artwork-for-print-be)

Comment: Just make your graphic that size, export it and view it at 100% to see if the resolution is OK to you.

Comment: You are probably increasing the size of the image by about 4.15, so 600/4.15 = ±144.5 pixels/inch, which, for some applications may be enough. Talk to your printer.

Comment: The proportions are wrong.

On Black the A4. On Gray the defined height. On red the difference in width. https://i.stack.imgur.com/QzCod.png

But as the resolution goes, it will be fine. https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/85476/billboard-sized-layout/85536#85536

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Billboard sized layout](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/85476/billboard-sized-layout)